# How to add Or to a While Loop in VB?

Tags: vb.net, loops, while-loop

Currently, lets say that I have this code:

```
     While r <> "HI"
        r = RandomStringGenerator(1)
        time = time + 1
        Console.WriteLine(r)
    End While
```

how can I make it so that i can say basically this:

```
    While r <> "HI" Or While r <> "BY"
        r = RandomStringGenerator(1)
        time = time + 1
        Console.WriteLine(r)
    End While
```

I've alreadly tried:

```
    While r <> "HI" Or r <> "BY"
        r = RandomStringGenerator(1)
        time = time + 1
        Console.WriteLine(r)
    End While
```

But it still doesn't work! What's up with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've written your conditional it will always be true and the loop will go infinitely.

```
r <> "HI" Or r <> "BY"
```

This essentially says

> If r is not equal to "Hi" or r is not equal to "By"

This will be true for every single string in existence.  It sounds like you want to continue if the string is neither "hi" or "by".  If so try the following

```
While r <> "HI" AndAlso r <> "BY"
    r = RandomStringGenerator(1)
    time = time + 1
    Console.WriteLine(r)
End While
```

One minor final point is you should prefer `OrElse` to plain `Or` and `AndAlso` to plain `And`.  The former versions are both short circuiting operations while the latter or not.